# Copying data from 1 table to another, but clear data before copy

Tags: excel, vba

Probably a really simple one, but can't seem to work out why my code isn't working.

I have a table that is auto filtered based on a loop.  For each loop I need to copy the filtered data from one table to a new sheet, but in case of removal of lines, want to clear the contents of the destination table before the data copies.

I've tried looking at the data in break mode but it just doesn't execute those lines of code at all.

My current code works, but I'd like it to be a little more useful.

Current code, copies a filtered range based on a loop to row 20 in a sheet named the same as the filter:

However I now want to improve it by clearing the target data table before I copy and now not specify that the data has to be copied to Row 20, merely the first row of the data.

But my new code just doesn't execute.

Sorry also can't get the Code tags to work either!!

I feel I'm close, but just can't get it!  Any help would be much appreciated.

Working Code:

```
 On Error Resume Next

      With Sourcetable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        With Sheets(Company_Name)

        On Error Resume Next
          .Rows(20).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
       End With
    End With
```

Broken Code:

```
 On Error Resume Next

Sheets(Company_Name).Listobjects(1).ClearContents

      With Sourcetable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        With Sheets(Company_Name)

        On Error Resume Next
          .ListObjects(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
       End With
    End With
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: You shouldn't need `On Error Resume Next` to make your code work. Comment out those lines and see if it throws an error anywhere

Comment: I've taken it out and the code moves through the lines but doesn't actually do any operation.  This is part of a much bigger code and I'm not sure whether there might be something in there that's stopping its execution.  I could post the full code but last I checked it ran to several word pages and is probably not quite as streamlined as it should be given that I'm a vba newbie.

Comment: I've fixed the first part of the code to clear existing data in the target table,  by replacing this: `Sheets(Company_Name).ListObjects(1).Clearcontents` with `With Sheets(cOMPANY_nAME).ListObjects(1)
                    .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.count - 1, .DataBodyRange.Columns.count).Rows.Delete
                    .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
                End With`.  But am now stuck on copying data to the first row of the target table as I don't know how to reference this as this won't be the same row on everysheet or table although column remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Solved it finally, I knew I was close:

```
'Clear Existing Data in target table only and resize table to 1 row (excluding header row)

With Sheets(Company_Name).ListObjects(1)
    .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.count - 1, .DataBodyRange.Columns.count).Rows.Delete
    .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
End With

'Define last row of Target Table (which will be first as all data cleared in previous step)

lrow = Sheets(Company_Name).Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

'Copy visible data from source table to first row of target table      
With Sourcetable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    With Sheets(Company_Name)
        .Range("A" & lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End With
```